# How to visualise Galois Vector Array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, fft, galois-field

I have this [data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/YDataVector.mat), **(255x1 gf)**.
It is FFT processed signal data.
I want to visualise it.
I do not find any conversion function back to integer or double, or any plotting function for Galois Vector Array.

I found that you can run **fftshift** to the data which gives an array, probably the data.
I run

```
sami = fftshift(YDataVector)
```

I get

```
sami = GF(2^8) array. Primitive polynomial = D^8+D^4+D^3+D^2+1 (285 decimal)

Array elements = 

          25
         232
          36
         124
         220
         141
         161
         111
          56
         190
         209
         205
         ...
```

**How can you get the array elements to an integer list?** I see now the values as integer, but they are still in the variable **sami** as **gf** format.

**How can you plot or visualise Galois Vector in Matlab?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field array elements of a `gf` Galois field object are stored in the attibute `x`:

```
>> x = sami.x;
>> whos x
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  x         255x1              1020  uint32
```